# MacBook / OSX can't access router/gateway web admin page - but other devices in same network can

Tags: networking, macos, router, gateway

### Problem

I’m trying to access my router web admin page, `http://192.168.0.1/`, from my MacBook. I can easily access the web admin page from other devices, like my Windows machine and my iPhone. But not from the MacBook.

All devices are on the same local wifi network, and there is no network filters/whitelist/blacklist on the router.

### Setup

---

**MacBook with OSX**

*This machine **can’t** access the web admin page via Chrome/Firefox/Safari*

1. Firewall is disabled
2. Bitdefender Antivirus is disabled
3. I have tried Chrome/Firefox/Safari

```
OSX Version:    10.14.6 
Network:        DHCP

IP:             192.168.0.118
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway/Router: 192.168.0.1
```

For some initial debugging:

```
nc -v 192.168.0.1 80 
> nc: connectx to 192.168.0.1 port 80 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

```
ping 192.168.0.1                          
> PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.120 ms
```

```
curl http://192.168.0.1/
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.1 port 80: Operation timed out
```

---

**PC with Windows**

*This machine **can** access the web admin page via Chrome/Firefox*

```
Win Version:    10.1903
Network:        DHCP

IP:             192.168.0.115
Subnet Mask:    255.255.255.0
Gateway/Router: 192.168.0.1
```

For some initial debugging:

```
nc -v 192.168.0.1 80
Connection to 192.168.0.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

```
ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.70 ms
```

```
curl http://192.168.0.1/
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML ...
```

---

**iPhone**

*This machine **can** access the web admin page via Safari/Chrome*

---

Anyone has any idea what's preventing the MacBook from viewing the page?

Comment: Some system-wide (http) proxy maybe?

Comment: No, no proxies configured